# Intermediate vector naming convention when converting 3D Vector to Spherical Coord

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, spherical-coordinates

Given the "Red" arrow as the vector of interest in the image below, is there a standard (or practical) name for the "Blue" vector?

This is for the purpose of naming variables/methods related to the Blue vector. Conceptually I am thinking of it as the polar-shadow of the Red vector, but naming my variable "VectorShadow" will likely be ambiguous for the next programmer looking at my code.

For context the code is simply converting [3D Cartesian Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Three_dimensions) to/from [Spherical Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

[image: 3D Cartesian Vector]

Comment: Your blue vector is just the vector projection of the red vector into the $xy$-plane. So some variation on 'vector projection' would work as a variable name.

Comment: $v_{blue}=v_{red}\cdot (\vec{x}\vec{x}+\vec{z}\vec{z})$. Where $\vec{x}$ is a unit vector in x direction. So I would call it "VectorProjection" (onto the x-z plane)

Comment: Ok, good enough. thanks.